# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: how to run code with a newer version of Java Runtime

Tags: java, javac, .class-file

While compiling from the command line, an error occurs, how do I get the required version of Java Runtime?

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: hello has been compiled by a
>   more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 57.0),
>   this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions
>   up to 52.0

```
C:\Users\s\Documents\Documents>javac hello.java

C:\Users\s\Documents\Documents>java hello
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: hello has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 57.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Which version of Java do you have installed?

Comment: @NoahBroyles  java version "1.8.0_231"

Comment: javac version 13.0.1

Comment: @SwetaJain Make sure you are using the same JDK version as your JRE.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're using a different JRE than you have Java compiler.

```
java -version
```

and

```
javac -version
```

and you should see a difference in version.

Once you confirm that, you can then either fix the path issue causing the difference or set a compilation target with javac

```
javac -target 1.8 hello.java
```

as an example

Comment: it isn't showing me java version

Comment: @SwetaJain who isn't? If the first two commands Mike gave you don't work, try `-version` instead of `--version` (the latter was introduced with java9 iirc). If that still doesn't work, download an actual java runtime, because what you're using is probably trash.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca 
C:\Users\s\Documents\Documents>javac --version
javac 13.0.1

C:\Users\s\Documents\Documents>java --version
Unrecognized option: --version
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: @SwetaJain do the java one as `java -version` instead of --

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca ok  'java version "1.8.0_231"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_231-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.231-b11, mixed mode)' and javac 13.0.1 . What is it supposed to be ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca What exactly am I supposed to do?

Comment: Check that those versions match or at least that `javac -version` < `java -version`

Comment: If you have a 1.8 JRE and a Java 13 JDK it might be that you have different versions in your PATH, and/or in an order that you're not expecting. Do you need a JRE1.8 as well as JDK 13? If not the quickest answer might be to uninstall 1.8